# Install 3rd party libary on AWS Lambda execution environment

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to install a native library (using RPM) for an AWS Lambda function.

I have found [this blogpost](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/) (Native Modules section) but I have no idea where to write these Linux commands. Does AWS Lambda have a console that I can get a hold with? Or how else can I install a native library? (I cannot build it locally and just copy the binary in the zip.)

Answer (score 3):

They are actually installing and setting up packages on a separate machine and then zipping the result up for deployment.

In the first example they use their own local machine, in the second example they create an Amazon Linux instance and build the packages there (as they need to build against the Amazon Linux libraries - which is what Lambda runs on).

Essentially, you need to be able to create a statically compiled version of your native library and deploy that in your zip file along with your function. The console they are using is not on the Lambda instance itself.

Comment: Any way to create a statically compiled version of the lib if i only have the denamically compiled one at hand?

Comment: Probably not, as it would need to be compiled against Amazon Linux with specific flags. The rough steps are described in the post you linked. As they mention, it isn't possible with all packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found this really helpful project for precompiling binaries to include in your application zip file. Many of the common libraries are in here.

https://github.com/lambci/yumda

(no affiliation)