# How to get git and all its dependencies in zip for AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, git, aws-lambda

This will sound really basic to some, but I'm overwhelmed.  I need to make a portable version of git for Linux such that a program could run `/path/to/folder/git` successfully. I assume `git` has dependencies such that if all I put in the folder was that file, some features wouldn't work.

I found the [Linux download page](https://git-scm.com/download/linux) with a link to the latest tarball: [git-2.40.0.tar.gz](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.40.0.tar.gz); I've no idea what to do next.  I'm guessing there's some compiling to do (how?). I can work with either a Mac or Windows machine.

PS: It's not important that I compile from source if there is an easier but safe way to get the portable folder for Linux git.

### Adding Context in case it matters

I actually need the executable in a zip file, within a `/bin` folder.  This is because it will be uploaded to AWS as a Lambda layer.  There's a project that did exactly this, but is using an old version of git (see `layers.zip` in this [git repo folder](https://github.com/lambci/git-lambda-layer/tree/master/lambda2))

As for the relevant Linux version, [Amazon says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html):

> you must compile and build these libraries using a Linux development machine so that the binaries are compatible with [Amazon Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html)

Comment: The lambda layer link looks fine; if you really need a Git version which is not yet available from the official repos, you actually do need to recompile it, probably based on the packaging for the previous version.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/download/linux points to https://ius.io/ for getting a recent RPM package from a third-party source. I have not explored this in more detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542697/install-3rd-party-libary-on-aws-lambda-execution-environment has some tips for AWS Lambda in particular, though it basically just links to an off-site resource.

Comment: If you want to compile from source on a non-Linux platform you might want to explore Docker, which lets you run Amazon Linux in a container. Then just export the compiled binaries from the container. But how exactly to recompile Git for this specific platform is a broad enough topic to require a separate question.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need git in a lambda?

Comment: @Paolo yes I'm trying to execute git within a Lambda

Comment: Why, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Paolo I'm building a git repo browser for remote repos; I'd like to get a list of all files and directories in a git repo at HEAD without downloading the files.  I do that by executing "git clone --depth=1 --filter=blob:none --no-checkout", then executing "git ls-tree" to get the tree entries.  My application is written in Go, but I haven't found a good Go library that will handle this for me.